# i want to achieve the animation so that two text doesn't overlaps

Tags: html, css, sass

https://codepen.io/shoumiksk/pen/bGoVdgE

here is the codepen link of what i want to achieve, plus i dont want the heading to slide down when there is some text in the input field. Now when i use valid like this the heading animation stops

```
.inputdiv input:valid + .content .contenttext {}
```

Is there any other way to do it?

*ignore mis-alignment of the input field, that's according to my ui*

Comment: I think you can do it with JS. When input field is not empty, don't move the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo selector `:placeholder-shown` for that. But then you have to define a placeholder, in your case ist a whitespace `placeholder=" "`.

Result: https://codepen.io/yourbraineatsyou/pen/XWeZogq

More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/